# Spring Boot Data JPA сaused by: Error accessing field

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

community!

I get an error (Error accessing field) when in **application.properties** I change the value (**spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto**) from **create-drop** to **validate** or **update**.

The error occurs when I try to get the **OwnerProfile** object from the database.

I use:

```
spring boot: 2.4.1

postgresql driver: 42.2.5
```

```java
Caused by: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Error accessing field [private java.lang.Long giveawaystatistics.model.OwnerProfile.pk] by reflection for persistent property [giveawaystatistics.model.OwnerProfile#pk] : 1; nested exception is org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private java.lang.Long giveawaystatistics.model.OwnerProfile.pk] by reflection for persistent property [giveawaystatistics.model.OwnerProfile#pk] : 1
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:331) ~[spring-orm-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233) ~[spring-orm-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551) ~[spring-orm-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) ~[spring-tx-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-tx-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:145) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy98.findOwnerProfileByPk(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.gmail.andreyzarazka.giveawaystatistics.service.impl.OwnerProfileServiceImpl.info(OwnerProfileServiceImpl.java:50) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.gmail.andreyzarazka.giveawaystatistics.GiveawayStatisticsApp.lambda$commandLineRunner$0(GiveawayStatisticsApp.java:44) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:804) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private java.lang.Long giveawaystatistics.model.OwnerProfile.pk] by reflection for persistent property [giveawaystatistics.model.OwnerProfile#pk] : 1
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:75) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.AbstractComponentTuplizer.getPropertyValue(AbstractComponentTuplizer.java:59) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.getPropertyValue(ComponentType.java:419) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.getHashCode(ComponentType.java:246) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.EntityUniqueKey.generateHashCode(EntityUniqueKey.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.EntityUniqueKey.<init>(EntityUniqueKey.java:48) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.loadByUniqueKey(EntityType.java:748) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:467) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad$EntityResolver.lambda$static$0(TwoPhaseLoad.java:605) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntityEntryLoadedState(TwoPhaseLoad.java:248) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:182) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:151) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1200) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:1001) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:959) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2850) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2832) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2664) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2659) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:400) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1414) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1625) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1593) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1641) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getSingleResult(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:406) ~[spring-orm-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy115.getSingleResult(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:196) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:88) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:155) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:143) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:131) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Long field giveawaystatistics.model.OwnerProfile.pk to java.lang.Long
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:419) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:71) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    ... 69 common frames omitted
```

My **application.properties** file looks like this

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/gsdb
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

```java
@Entity(name = "OwnerProfile")
@Table(name = "owner_profile",
        uniqueConstraints = {
                @UniqueConstraint(
                        name = "owner_profile_pk_unique",
                        columnNames = "pk"),
                @UniqueConstraint(
                        name = "owner_profile_username_unique",
                        columnNames = "username")})
public class OwnerProfile implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "owner_profile_sequence",
            sequenceName = "owner_profile_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = SEQUENCE,
            generator = "owner_profile_sequence")
    @Column(
            name = "id",
            updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(
            name = "pk",
            nullable = false,
            updatable = false)
    private Long pk;

    @Column(
            name = "username",
            nullable = false,
            columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String username;

    @Column(
            name = "profile_pic_url",
            nullable = false,
            columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String profilePicUrl;

    @Column(
            name = "phone_number",
            nullable = true,
            columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String phoneNumber;

    @OneToOne(
            mappedBy = "ownerProfile",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Company company;

    public OwnerProfile() {
    }

    public OwnerProfile(SelfProfile profile) {
        this.pk = profile.getPk();
        this.username = profile.getUsername();
        this.profilePicUrl = profile.getProfilePicUrl();
        this.phoneNumber = profile.getPhoneNumber();
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getPk() {
        return pk;
    }

    public void setPk(Long pk) {
        this.pk = pk;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getProfilePicUrl() {
        return profilePicUrl;
    }

    public void setProfilePicUrl(String profilePicUrl) {
        this.profilePicUrl = profilePicUrl;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public Company getCompany() {
        return company;
    }

    public void setCompany(Company company) {
        this.company = company;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Company)) return false;
        Company company = (Company) o;
        return getId().equals(company.getId())
                && getPk().equals(company.getPk())
                && getUsername().equals(company.getUsername());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getId(), getPk(), getUsername());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "OwnerProfileService{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", pk=" + pk +
                ", username='" + username + '\'' +
                ", profilePicUrl='" + profilePicUrl + '\'' +
                ", phoneNumber='" + phoneNumber + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

```java
@Entity(name = "Company")
@Table(
        name = "company",
        uniqueConstraints = {
                @UniqueConstraint(
                        name = "company_pk_unique",
                        columnNames = "pk"),
                @UniqueConstraint(
                        name = "company_username_unique",
                        columnNames = "username")})
public class Company implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "company_sequence",
            sequenceName = "company_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = SEQUENCE,
            generator = "company_sequence")
    @Column(
            name = "id",
            updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(
            name = "pk",
            nullable = false,
            updatable = false)
    private Long pk;

    @Column(
            name = "username",
            nullable = false,
            columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String username;

    @Column(
            name = "full_name",
            nullable = true,
            columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String fullName;

    @Column(
            name = "profile_pic_url",
            nullable = false,
            columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String profilePicUrl;

    @Column(
            name = "profile_pic_id",
            nullable = true,
            columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String profilePicId;

    @Column(
            name = "following_count",
            nullable = false)
    private Integer followingCount;

    @Column(
            name = "biography",
            nullable = true,
            columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String biography;

    @Column(
            name = "account_type",
            nullable = false)
    private Integer accountType;

    @Column(
            name = "is_private",
            nullable = false,
            columnDefinition = "boolean default false")
    private Boolean isPrivate;

    @Column(
            name = "is_business",
            nullable = false,
            columnDefinition = "boolean default false")
    private Boolean isBusiness;

    @OneToOne(
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(
            name = "owner_profile_pk",
            referencedColumnName = "pk",
            foreignKey = @ForeignKey(
                    name = "owner_profile_pk_fk"))
    private OwnerProfile ownerProfile;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "company",
            orphanRemoval = true,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<CompanyRegistration> companyRegistrations = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "company",
            orphanRemoval = true,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<GiveawayFollowers> giveawayFollowers = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "company",
            orphanRemoval = true,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<TargetAudience> targetAudiences = new HashSet<>();

    public Company() {
    }

    public Company(User user) {
        this.pk = user.getPk();
        this.username = user.getUsername();
        this.fullName = user.getFull_name();
        this.profilePicUrl = user.getProfile_pic_url();
        this.profilePicId = user.getProfile_pic_id();
        this.followingCount = user.getFollowing_count();
        this.biography = user.getBiography();
        this.accountType = user.getAccount_type();
        this.isPrivate = user.is_private();
        this.isBusiness = user.is_business();
    }

    public Company(Long pk,
                   String username,
                   String fullName,
                   String profilePicUrl,
                   String profilePicId,
                   Integer followingCount,
                   String biography,
                   Integer accountType,
                   Boolean isPrivate,
                   Boolean isBusiness) {
        this.pk = pk;
        this.username = username;
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.profilePicUrl = profilePicUrl;
        this.profilePicId = profilePicId;
        this.followingCount = followingCount;
        this.biography = biography;
        this.accountType = accountType;
        this.isPrivate = isPrivate;
        this.isBusiness = isBusiness;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getPk() {
        return pk;
    }

    public void setPk(Long pk) {
        this.pk = pk;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public String getProfilePicUrl() {
        return profilePicUrl;
    }

    public void setProfilePicUrl(String profilePicUrl) {
        this.profilePicUrl = profilePicUrl;
    }

    public String getProfilePicId() {
        return profilePicId;
    }

    public void setProfilePicId(String profilePicId) {
        this.profilePicId = profilePicId;
    }

    public Integer getFollowingCount() {
        return followingCount;
    }

    public void setFollowingCount(Integer followingCount) {
        this.followingCount = followingCount;
    }

    public String getBiography() {
        return biography;
    }

    public void setBiography(String biography) {
        this.biography = biography;
    }

    public Integer getAccountType() {
        return accountType;
    }

    public void setAccountType(Integer accountType) {
        this.accountType = accountType;
    }

    public Boolean getPrivate() {
        return isPrivate;
    }

    public void setPrivate(Boolean aPrivate) {
        isPrivate = aPrivate;
    }

    public Boolean getBusiness() {
        return isBusiness;
    }

    public void setBusiness(Boolean business) {
        isBusiness = business;
    }

    public OwnerProfile getOwnerProfile() {
        return ownerProfile;
    }

    public void setOwnerProfile(OwnerProfile ownerProfile) {
        this.ownerProfile = ownerProfile;
    }

    public Set<CompanyRegistration> getCompanyRegistrations() {
        return companyRegistrations;
    }

    public void addCompanyRegistration(CompanyRegistration companyRegistration) {
        companyRegistrations.add(companyRegistration);
    }

    public void removeCompanyRegistration(CompanyRegistration companyRegistration) {
        companyRegistrations.remove(companyRegistration);
    }

    public Set<GiveawayFollowers> getGiveawayFollowers() {
        return giveawayFollowers;
    }

    public void addGiveawayFollower(GiveawayFollowers giveawayFollowers) {
        this.giveawayFollowers.add(giveawayFollowers);
    }

    public void removeGiveawayFollower(GiveawayFollowers giveawayFollowers) {
        this.giveawayFollowers.remove(giveawayFollowers);
    }

    public Set<TargetAudience> getTargetAudiences() {
        return targetAudiences;
    }

    public void addTargetAudience(TargetAudience targetAudience) {
        this.targetAudiences.add(targetAudience);
    }

    public void removeTargetAudience(TargetAudience targetAudience) {
        this.targetAudiences.remove(targetAudience);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Company)) return false;
        Company company = (Company) o;
        return getId().equals(company.getId())
                && getPk().equals(company.getPk())
                && getUsername().equals(company.getUsername());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getId(), getPk(), getUsername());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CompanyDetails{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", pk=" + pk +
                ", username='" + username + '\'' +
                ", fullName='" + fullName + '\'' +
                ", profilePicUrl='" + profilePicUrl + '\'' +
                ", profilePicId=" + profilePicId +
                ", followingCount=" + followingCount +
                ", biography='" + biography + '\'' +
                ", accountType=" + accountType +
                ", isPrivate=" + isPrivate +
                ", isBusiness=" + isBusiness +
                '}';
    }
}
```

```java
public interface OwnerProfileRepository extends JpaRepository<OwnerProfile, Long> {
    Optional<OwnerProfile> findOwnerProfileByPk(Long pk);
}
```

Any idea why this is happening and how you can fix it?

Comment: Huh, weird. Does it work if you remove `company` from `OwnerProfile`?

Comment: Hi, crizzis!
Yes it works, but I need to maintain BiDirectional in a 1 to 1 relationship between these classes.

Comment: Yeah, Hibernate doesn't like bidirectional associations based on non-PK columns, I'm not sure there's a way around that (other than switching to `OwnerProfile.id`), maybe you could use `@JoinFormula` for `OwnerProfile.company` instead but you'll need to check

Comment: Thanks, crizzis!